# Вопрос по поводу спецификатора alignas

Tags: c++

С помощью спецификатора `alignas` можно явно задать необходимое выравнивание для объекта. Пример:

```
alignas(short) alignas(long long) int a;
```

Здесь среди всех спецификаторов `alignas`, применённых к переменной `a`, будет использоваться самое строгое требование по выравниванию.

Но есть один момент, смысл которого мне не ясен. Если самое строгое требование по выравниванию среди всех спецификаторов `alignas`, слабее, чем собственное требование по выравниванию типа переменной `a`, то программа считается неправильной. Это требование стандарта языка. Пример:

```
alignas(short) int a; //Ошибка.
```

Если требования по выравниванию у типа `short` слабее, чем требования по выравниванию для типа `int` (так оно обычно и бывает на практике), то приведённый выше код является неправильным.

Почему стандарт языка хочет, чтобы приведённый код был ошибочным? Почему бы просто не проигнорировать спецификатор `alignas(short)`, если требование по выравниванию у типа `int` строже чем у типа `short`? Ведь предыдущий пример я могу переписать так:

```
alignas(short) alignas(int) int a;
```

Comment: потому что в первом случае, вы говорите "хочу ТОЧНО как у short", а компилятор говорит - нельзя. А во втором случае вы говорите "хочу как у short или как у int", компилятор говорит - short нельзя, а int - можно, работаем дальше. Если бы первый код не давал ошибку, то требование к выравниванию было бы просьбой, а не требованием. И никаких гарантий, что alignas сработал не было бы.

Comment: @Croessmah "И никаких гарантий, что alignas сработал не было бы" Это ещё почему? Если объект удовлетворяет некоторому требованию по выравниванию, то он удовлетворяет и **всем** менее строгим требованиям по выравниванию. Таким образом, здесь: `int a;` переменная `a` выровнена не только так, как того требует тип `int`, но и как того требуют типы `short` и `char`.

Comment: @Джонни Кэтсвилл, если вам дадут место  для вашего груза, размер которого  много больше размера этого места, то вы же скажете, что это ошибка _ ваш груз  имеет размер больше и туда не влазит?  Как поместить  -65536, имеющий бинарный код 16 единиц и 16 нулей  в 16 бит?.. Игнорировать команду нельзя. С таким успехом компилятор мог бы игнорировать все строки, где есть ошибка. А это привело бы к тому, что получился бы код без ошибок, но совсем не тот, что вы хотели.

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл вот именно, что вы просите нарушить выравнивание предусмотренное для int. Допустим, выравнивание для short - 2 байта, для int - 4 байта. Если компилятор применит эту директиву, то объект должен быть уже выровнен как short, т.е. на 2 байта. А значит мы можем как попасть в адрес кратный 4-ем, и удовлетворить требование к выравниванию int, так и не попасть.

Comment: @Croessmah, "А значит мы можем как попасть в адрес кратный 4-ем, и удовлетворить требование к выравниванию int, так и не попасть" Что значит можем не попасть? Если разместить объект по адресу, кратному четырём, то он будет удовлетворять требованию по выравниванию **и** для `int`, **и** для `short`. "просите нарушить выравнивание предусмотренное для int" - `int` изначально удовлетворяет требованиям по выравниванию для `short`. [basic.align/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.align#5): "An address that satisfies an alignment requirement **also satisfies any weaker valid alignment requirement**".

Comment: @Croessmah, Компилятор видит, что мы просим выровнять объект по адресу, кратному двум, также он видит, что адрес должен быть кратен четырём. Компилятор может удовлетворить **оба требования одновременно**. Или вы считаете, что здесь: `alignas(int) char a[2];` второй элемент массива `a` также удовлетворяет требованию по выравниванию для `int`? Или это не валидный код? @ARHovsepyan, чтобы удовлетворить требования по выравниванию нет никакой нужды запихивать 32-битный `int` в 16 бит. Достаточно первый байт объекта типа `int` разместить по определённому адресу.

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл вы выравниваете массив, а не отдельные элементы. Вот массив и будет выровнен как int.

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл "Если разместить объект по адресу, кратному четырём" так вы сами говорите ему, что нужно разместить по адресу, кратному двум, а не четырем. Четыре - частный случай выравнивания на границу 2 байта. Так же, как адрес кратный 6 - частный случай выравнивания по границе 2. Например, есть структура выровненная по int, с двумя полями - первое short, второе - int. Если мы ко второму int'ту сделаем выравнивание 2, то ожидается, что int будет следовать за short сразу, без padding'ов, так ведь? И вот вам казус - нужно разместить по адресу, кратному 2, а не 4.

Comment: @Croessmah "Если мы ко второму int'ту сделаем выравнивание 2, то ожидается, что int будет следовать за short сразу, без padding'ов, так ведь?" Нет. Я ожидаю, что второе поле структуры будет удовлетворять двум требованиям по выравниванию: 1) то которое я попросил, в вашем примере - это `2`, и 2) собственному требованию по выравниванию для типа, в вашем примере - это `4`.  Таким образом, за первым полем структуры будет следовать двухбайтный padding и только потом второе поле. Если я напишу `alignas(long long) int a;`, то переменная `a` не перестанет удовлетворять выравниванию для `int`.

Comment: @Croessmah, не уверен, что пример со структурой корректен. Да, компиляторы стараются упаковать поля структуры плотно. Если первое и второе поля структуры имеют одинаковый тип, то на практике между ними не будет никаких padding'ов. Но стандарт языка не требует отсутствия padding'а. Между двумя последовательными полями типа `int` компилятор мог бы вставить padding размером с `int` или размером с 10 `int`'ов - это не противоречит стандарту.

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл тогда требование выравнивания по 2 для int не имеет никакой юридической силы (и смысла) и инструкция просто бесполезна, фактически, это уже будет просьба, а не требование.

Comment: @Croessmah, 1) " тогда требование выравнивания по 2 для int не имеет никакой юридической силы (и смысла) и инструкция просто бесполезна", ну собственно как и здесь: `alignas(short) alignas(int) alignas(long long) int a;` - выравнивание `short` менее строгое, чем у `long long`, и чем у `int` - спецификатор `alignas(short)` оказался бесполезен (и `alignas(int)` бесполезен), но стандарт почему-то  не считает это ошибкой.

Comment: @Croessmah, 2) "Если вы задаете для int выравнивание по 2, то предполагаете, что два таких последовательных объекта будут расположены вплотную друг к другу с разницей в адресах в два байта" **Нет**. Я предполагаю, что к объекту будет применено самое строгое выравнивание, **среди всех затребованных выравниваний**. Также как в коде `alignas(short) alignas(int) alignas(long long) int a;` выбирается самое строгое выравнивание среди затребованных, а остальные игнорируются. С чего вдруг `alignas(short)` обязан упаковать `int` в два байта, если его собственное выравнивание строже, чем у `short`?

Comment: @Croessmah, 3) "Если вы задаете для int выравнивание по 2, то предполагаете, что два таких последовательных объекта будут расположены вплотную друг к другу с разницей в адресах в два байта" + "вы выравниваете массив, а не отдельные элементы. Вот массив и будет выровнен как int." Ну смотрите: `alignas(int) char arr[5];` - массив `arr` выровнен как `int`, но разместить последовательно два таких массива, чтобы разница в их адресах была 4 байта - невозможно.

Answer (score 1):

Один из самых ранних черновиков, который мне удалось найти, и в котором обсуждается введение требований по выравниванию в стандарт языка — это документ от 2002 года: [n1546](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2003/n1546.pdf) — Alignment Proposal. Вот цитата оттуда:

> The *alignment-specifier* can be used in variable declarations just like a *storage-class-specifier*. It can be used portably to specify the alignment requirement for the variable being declared.
>
> In general alignment requirement for a type can be strengthened, weakened or unchanged. Open question is whether it makes any sense to weaken the alignment requirements. The only place where it seems to be useful is the creation of “packed” class types. Since on many platforms accessing a misaligned variable is very costly and “packing” is not directly related to alignment I propose not to allow weakening.

Из написанного следует, что спецификатор выравнивания обязателен к выполнению. Т.е. конструкция

```
alignas(short) int a;
```

означает, не только то, что переменная `a` должна быть выравнена по типу `short`, но и то, что она **не обязана** быть выравнена по типу `int`. Т.к. на практике доступ к невыравненной переменной может быть проблематичен, было принято решение, запретить ослабление требований по выравниванию:

> If the *alignment-specifier* would weaken the alignment requirement of the type, the program is ill-formed and diagnostics are required

C тех пор смысл спецификатора выравнивания немного изменился. Да, он всё ещё требует, чтобы объект удовлетворял запрашиваемому выравниванию, но теперь спецификатор выравнивания **не отменяет** более строгие требования по выравниванию. То есть здесь:

```
alignas(short) alignas(int) alignas(long long) int a;
```

спецификатор `alignas(short)` не отменяет требований спецификаторов `alignas(int)` и `alignas(long long)`, а спецификатор `alignas(int)` не отменяет требование спецификатора `alignas(long long)`.

Тем не менее, писать так:

```
alignas(char) alignas(short) int a;
```

всё ещё нельзя. Среди спецификаторов выравнивания должен найтись хотябы один, который запрашивает выравнивание не слабее, чем то выравнивавние, которое было бы у переменной `a`, если бы она не имела никаких спецификаторов выравнивания.

По сути это требование стандарта сохранилось со времён того самого черновика от 2002 года, хотя формулировка немного изменилась ([dcl.align/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.align#5)):

> The combined effect of all *alignment-specifiers* in a declaration shall not specify an alignment that is less strict than the alignment that would be required for the entity being declared if all *alignment-specifiers* appertaining to that entity were omitted.

В документе-обсуждении от 2020 года [P2152R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2152r0.pdf) — Querying the Alignment of an Object — рассматривается вариант **игнорирования** запроса на более слабое выравнивание. Но этот вариант не рекомендуется, т.к. он нарушает совместимость с языком C и игнорирование явного запроса на выравнивание — это спорное решение:

> Add that describing a weaker alignment for an object than required by its objecttype will be ignored.
> ...
> the suggestions are for behaviour weaker than of C’s struct, and will increase the difference between the languages regarding the struct keyword, as well as ignore the alignment explicit demand, therefore I don’t recommend it.

Для того, чтобы быть уверенным, что запрашиваемое выравнивание `A` не слабее, чем собственное выравнивание у некоторого объекта типа `T`, стандарт языка рекомендует добавить к запрашиваемому выравниванию ещё и `alignas(T)` ([dcl.align/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.align#example-3)):

> [*Example 3*: An aligned buffer with an alignment requirement of `A` and holding `N` elements of type `T` can be declared as:
>
> ```
>    alignas(T) alignas(A) T buffer[N];
> ```
>
> Specifying `alignas(T)` ensures that the final requested alignment will not be weaker than `alignof(T)`, and therefore the program will not be ill-formed.
> — *end example*]